# Stop/Start Service hosted in IIS using Powershell or WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi

I Have some WCF services hosted in iis. Using powershell script i want to stop and start individual services(or applications).i found so many articles for stop App-pool.but i want a specific application to be stopped.And i have heard that with WMI we can make it.But i could not find any relevant script for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS, you can only stop an "Application" by stopping it's associated Application Pool. Thus the necessity to stop a specific application would require you to organize your applications into Application Pools such that you would only stop a single (or group) of applications when stopping a specific Application Pool.

By organizing your Applications into multiple Application Pools, you can thus utilize the app-pool.vbs or Powershell or WMI interfaces to stop the specific AppPool associated with the application you wish to stop.